# Long lasting Declarative Service activate method

Tags: osgi, osgi-ds

I tried to understand [from the OSGi specs](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html) what it should happen in case an activate method blocks indefinitely but I did not find an answer. On the other hand, it seams that that Felix SCR has  `ds.lock.timeout.milliseconds` and `ds.stop.timeout.milliseconds` properties to manage activate/deactivate timeouts, right?

Questions:

- Why OSGi specs do not mention activate/deactivate deadlock management?
- In case a DS needs more time to run its activate method, is it wise to increase the default SCR `ds.lock.timeout.milliseconds` value? Or is it better to avoid the activate method altogether and register the service "by hand" using `context.registerService` in a dedicated thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a long initialization you mark the component `immediate`. In the activate method you start a background initialization. When your service is called, you block until the initialization is done. (Promises work very nice for this technique.)

```
@Component(immediate=true)
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
   Promise<Foo>  promise;

   @Activate void activate() { promise = begin(); }

   @Override
   public void foo() { promise.get().foo(); }
}
```

The advantage of this technique is that it allows many initializations to proceed in parallel.

The delegation you need is kind of ugly. If performance is not overly important you can easily create a proxy doing the actual work.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the only safe method is to spawn another thread in activate and register the service when your async code is finished.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this video [OSGI Best Practices by Eclipse Foundation](https://youtu.be/qVKCMjhiJBY?t=1209), you can start long lasting job in a seperate thread then register your service manually.

```
@Activate
public void activate(BundleContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.reg = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::longRunning);
}

@Deactivate
public void deactivate() {
    this.reg.thenAcceptAsync(ServiceRegistration::unregister);
}

private ServiceRegistration<TaskService> longRunning() {
    // long running call
    return context.registerService(TaskService.class, this, new Hashtable<String, String>());
}
```